# How can I set Android font dimension only once across all screen sizes?

Tags: android

I realize that in `dimens.xml` I have the option to specify values that are used throughout the entire app. So I can set up something like:

```
<dimen name="layoutFont">22dp</dimen>
```

However, with the way I have it set up, I then have to create similar declarations for `layoutLargeFont` and `layoutXlargeFont`, then I have to manually change all those variables in the layout files.

Is there a way to do a declaration for a single variable: `layoutFont` whose value is different when it is used in a Large or XLarge layout?

Comment: Please use `sp`, rather than `dp`, for font sizes, so your font size can scale with the user's preferred base font scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a TextAppearance for your theme. This will be applied to any TextView (and subclasses of TextView) that use the theme's default text appearance.

```
<style name="MyApp.Theme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <!-- other theme attrs -->
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/layout_font</item>
</style>
```

You can go a step further and define `textAppearanceSmall`, `textAppearanceMedium`, and `textAppearanceLarge`.

```
<style name="MyApp.Theme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <!-- other theme attrs -->
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmall">@style/TextAppearance.Small</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLarge">@style/TextAppearance.Large</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/layout_font</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/layout_font_small</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/layout_font_medium</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/layout_font_large</item>
</style>
```

And of course you would define these dimensions using the appropriate resource qualifiers (I recommend the smallest-width qualifiers, -sw###dp, as [described here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSWQuali) and [also here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts)). With all of this, you shouldn't have to set any textSize on anything unless it's for a specific purpose.

Answer (score 3):

add your dimens.xml in

```
  values-large  and values-xlarge
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers Here is the relevant documentation